# glColor4f - Cannot get full opacity when drawing

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm rewriting a renderer (part of a 2D game) to use OpenGL instead of SDL.
I have an issue with the following code:

```
void renderer_opengl::draw_rectangle_filled(int x, int y, int w, int h, SDL_Color color){
    glColor4f((1.0f/255)*color.r, (1.0f/255)*color.g, (1.0f/255)*color.b, (1.0f/255)*color.a);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        glVertex2f(x + w, y);
        glVertex2f(x + w, y + h);
        glVertex2f(x, y + h);
    glEnd();
    glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

(yeah I know this is deprecated GL, let's just ignore that now)
This draws a rectangle with the given colors and alpha value. The problem is that even when setting the color like this: `glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 1);` doesn't result in pure black, but instead a semi transparent black (similar to setting the alpha to 50% in the standard SDL renderer).

I have enabled blending like this:

```
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

I tried different parameters to `glBlendFunc` but nothing fixes the issue. I can never get a solid color. The rectangles are drawn over textures that are already rendered to the screen. (These rectangles should be black with around 70% alpha - so pretty dark, but still transparent). Thanks for any help.

Code that loads texture from a `std::unordered_map` of `SDL_Surface*`

```
void renderer_opengl::upload_surfaces(std::unordered_map<int, SDL_Surface*>* surfaces){
    for ( auto it = surfaces->begin(); it != surfaces->end(); ++it ){
        if(it->second != NULL && textures[it->first] == NULL){
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            GLuint TextureID = new_texture_id();
            glGenTextures(1, &TextureID);
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureID);
            int Mode = GL_RGB;
            if(it->second->format->BytesPerPixel == 4) {
                Mode = GL_RGBA;
            }
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Mode, it->second->w, it->second->h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, it->second->pixels);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            textures[it->first] = new texture(TextureID, Mode, it->second->w, it->second->h); //texture is just a struct that holds the GLuint, the Mode, width and height


       }
   }
}
```

The function that draws textures:

```
void renderer_opengl::draw_texture(int arg, int x, int y){
    texture* Texture = textures[arg];
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, Texture->TextureID);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   int Width = Texture->width;
   int Height = Texture->height;
   int X = x;
   int Y = y - Height;
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(X, Y+ Height, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(X + Width, Y + Height, 0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(X + Width, Y , 0);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(X, Y , 0);
    glEnd();
}
```

What I do in the initialization code that hasn't to do with setting up the viewport, aspect ratio, etc..

```
glEnable (GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
```

The whole rendering operation goes something like this:

1.

```
glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0); //Screen is cleared
glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
```

2. Calls to `draw_texture` and `draw_rectangle_filled` are made
3. `SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);` and then everything is displayed

Comment: `glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);` is not supposed to be pure black, it is supposed to be pure white.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry. I meant to write `glColor4f(0, 0, 0, 1);` that should be pure black. I edited the question :)

Comment: You need to provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Or at least show complete frame rendering code that reproduces the stated problem. This draw function looks fine, but who knows what else are you doing before / after?

Comment: The entire rendering is too much code to post here, but I will try to show the functions that load and draw a texture, as I think that where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by calling `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` before drawing a rectangle. I guess there was still a texture bound to the OpenGl context and that was causing the issue. Everything is perfect now.